# React Native - Stack navigation.navigate() does not refresh the screen - Need advise

Tags: react-native

I am building a react native app, where I have two components. Summary and Payment. Summary will show the current open due to be paid. From Summary Screen user can navigate to Payment Screen.

Initially the payment screen will have a drop down where user can select the payment method.

1. Total Amount
2. Current Amount Due
3. Other Amount

The problem here is , when I select some payment option and make a payment it goes back to Summary screen. When the user again tries to navigate to Payment Screen from summary, it shows the previously selected dropdown in the payment screen. I want the screen to be rendered as if it is the first time it is rendering. It should not be rendering the previously loaded screen.

Can someone please help me on this.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Payment", {
  accountBalance: this.state.totalAccountBalance,
  amountDue: this.state.amountDue,
  onPayment: this.handlePayment,
  navigationobj: this.props.navigation,
});
```

**First Navigate to Payment Screen**

[image: First Navigate]

**Second Navigate to Payment Screen... Drop down should show as 'Select an item'**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-navigation focus Listener to re render your focused screen

here is the usage https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/